# Nexus 6 Front Camera Upside Down

Tags: android

I know this question has been asked before, however, I'm unable to find any solutions that work.

The `Nexus 6` front camera always displays upside down in my app. Some of the solutions are to use "`setDisplayOrientation`", which does flip the camera on the screen. However, we encode the video with `frames` received from `onPreviewFrame`.

According to the `Android SDK Documentation`, `setDisplayOrientation` doesn't actually change the `byte[]` in `onPreviewFrame`.

> This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos. This method is not allowed to be called during preview.

If it is not possible to get the `Nexus 6` front camera `onPreviewFrame` frames in the `correct orientation`, what is the `fastest` way to flip each frame, without suffering a drop in fps.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your codes?

Comment: I can't.. The camera activity has a couple 1000 lines that I would need to go through. There is really nothing special about it though. Setting a preview size of 720p on the front camera using the original Camera api (Not Camera2). The front camera on the Nexus 6 is the only phone that we have seen this. A quick Google search shows that it's a Nexus 6 bug. Even Instagram and Snapchat had this issue at some point (although they seem to have fixed it). I doubt they need the raw frames from onPreviewFrame though.

Comment: I'll try to get ahold of a Nexus 6 tomorrow and create a stripped down camera app with the issue. This has been a big priority as a celebrity recently used the app and.. of course he had a Nexus 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this and keep fps high by using open cv to flip the frames.

```
yuvimage = opencv_core.IplImage.create(frame.getWith / 2, frame.getHeight / 2 * 3 / 2, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
yuvimage.getByteBuffer().clear();
yuvimage.getByteBuffer().put(halveYUV420(frame.getData(), frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight()));
rgbimage = opencv_core.IplImage.create(frame.getWidth / 2, frame.getHeight / 2, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
rgbimage.getByteBuffer().clear();
opencv_imgproc.cvCvtColor(yuvimage, rgbimage, opencv_imgproc.CV_YUV2BGR_NV21);
opencv_core.cvFlip(rgbimage, rgbimage, 0);
```

Comment: have you made this change only for nexus 6, or any other device had this issue?

Answer (score 3):

The code snippet under [Camera.setDisplayOrientation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#setDisplayOrientation%28int%29) resolved this issue for me. You need to try it.

Comment: Unfortunately this method doesn't work for the preview frames received in onPreviewFrame. "This does not affect the order of byte array passed in onPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera), JPEG pictures, or recorded videos. This method is not allowed to be called during preview." I was able to get it working with my solution above. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be to do the flipping inside the GPU itself.
Render the camera preview on a `GLSurfaceView` and use vertex shaders to flip the image upside down.
Then, use `glReadPixels` to get the bytes of the current frame.
I'm not sure about the performance of `glReadPixels` on other phones, but, it should be pretty fast in Nexus 6/5.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This looks like a valid solution, however, I have already fixed the problem in my answer (without taking a hit to fps) with JavaCV. This library was already being used for the video processing. Thank you for your solution!